Do I need parent and root pom in my project
I have project structure like:
+-module_a/pom.xml
+-parent/pom.xml (parent) // here is only pom.xml file
+-module_b/pom.xml
|
pom.xml (root)

Into the (root) pom are defined modules and build plugin.
Into parent pom are defined properties, dependencyManagament and repository.
Can I merge parent into root pom and inherit everything from root pom ?
I inherit this project and I don't understand why is compose like this. Do I need that pom.xml who is inside parent module alone ?

Yes, you should merge the parent into the root pom. It makes things simple.

I strongly recommend to put the staff from parent/pom.xml into the root pom ... that will make thins simpler... in the module_a/pom you can simply use the parent without using relativePath ...
